# How can I g_signal_connect() by ID rather than string name?

Tags: c, gtk, micro-optimization

The typical way to handle a button press in GTK is:

```
g_signal_connect(GTK_BUTTON(myButton), "pressed", G_CALLBACK(myButtonHandler), NULL);
```

However, I find it bad, slow, and unnecessary to use strings (such as `"pressed"`) for internal identification. If I can find the numerical signal ID that corrosponds to this, I can skip the parsing step. But how do I connect an event by ID rather than string name? I did a lot of digging and found [this](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gobject/gsignal.c), and I also learned that `g_signal_connect` is a macro that expands to `g_signal_connect_data`, but none of these quite solve my problem.

Is this possible, if so, how do I do this?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Parsing short strings, most likely only once at startup, should not be a noticeable issue. Using strings instead of IDs makes the system robust against different versions of libraries used during build and execution.

Comment: @Gerhardh But still, why strings instead of macros? Using strings for identification is terrible

Comment: I just mentioned why. Strings will not fail if you insert another string in the list. Try that with some enums used as ID.

Comment: @Gerhardh Macros won't fail either

Comment: The compiler doesn't know macros. They are expanded to strings or IDs. No difference here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`g_signal_connect_closure_by_id()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.signal_connect_closure_by_id.html) but then you have to create a `GClosure` structure to hold your callback and callback data.

I would really recommend against this, as it will add boilerplate to your code for little benefit. You generally only connect signals once. If you are connecting a signal in a tight loop, then you are probably doing something wrong, or you have a very unusual use case. Anyway, signal names are actually interned, which means that you are not even incurring the cost of string comparisons; only the cost of splitting the string at `:` if the signal has a detail annotation. Don't bother with optimizing this unless it is actually showing up as a bottleneck on your profiler graphs.